# TestCafe: import tests from another file into the current fixture

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, integration-testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a file `tests.js` that contains some `test(...)` definitions. I want to reuse these tests across multiple fixtures, preferably without making any modifications to the original code.

So I wrote a `main.js` that defines a fixture and imports `tests.js`, thereby "assembling" a test suite. (In case that works, I could write different driver files with different fixtures, importing the same `tests.js` from within each.)

However, I'm getting a `test is not defined` error when trying to execute `main.js`:

```
C:\Windows\Temp\dummy>testcafe chrome main.js --debug-on-fail
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.

ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\Temp\dummy\tests.js:1:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\Temp\dummy\main.js:7:1)

Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

Minimal sample:

```
// tests.js

test('wait', async t => {
    await t.wait(1);
});


// main.js

fixture `here goes the name`
    .page("http://localhost:3000")
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        // do stuff
    });

import "./tests";

/*
trick testcafe to scan the file;
based on https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2889#issuecomment-423859785

test();
*/
```

I already tried:

- removing the block comment hack (`test();`) - which gives `ERROR No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive.`
- moving the `tests.js` import to the top - still gives `test is not defined`
- importing `testcafe` from within `main.js` and `tests.js` - same error

Is there a way to make the `test` function "visible" to other files imported by the testcafe entrypoint file? Or will I actually need to modify my `tests.js` file in order to get this working? Maybe by adding the test definitions into a method, and invoking it from within `main.js` - as in the original code sample of [this issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2889)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't allow calling `fixture` and `test` functions outside the test scope. You can wrap your tests from the `tests.js` file in a function and call this function in the `main.js` file:

```js
// tests.js
export default function () {
   test('Test 1', () => {});
   test('Test 2', () => {});
   test('Test 3', () => {});
}
```

```js
// main.js
import defineTests from './tests';

defineTests();
```

See also: [Organize Tests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests.html)

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid it would eventually boil down to this :( One thing I don't understand, though, is why/how the imported file does not belong to the "test scope"; since, AFAIU, `tests.js` is imported and executed synchronously by `main.js`, which is already in TestCafe's "test scope".

Comment: @Janaka, this is due to the fact that all your test code is transpiled to vanilla JS. What is executing is the code resulting from this transpilation.

Comment: Thanks @hdorgeval! That also clarifies many of the other issues that I had about TestCafe :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the option `--disable-test-syntax-validation` on the TestCafe command-line

(works only in latest TestCafe version).

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I'm on `0.20.0` but hopefully this would help someone else :)